# Curious behaviour using gridExtra (ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I am trying to stack three plots on top of each other using the `gridExtra` package. I have tried the the first example that uses `grid.arrange` from [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-easy-way-to-mix-multiple-graphs-on-the-same-page-r-software-and-data-visualization), which works absolutely fine.

However, when I try to use my own plots, I get axes for each plot but no data, with all the formatting stripped out. Minimum working example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)    

popu_H0 <- seq(10, 30, length=100)
popu_H0_norm <- dnorm(popu_H0, mean = 20, sd = 4)

popu_H0_df <- as.data.frame(cbind(popu_H0, popu_H0_norm))
plot_H0 <- ggplot(popu_H0_df, aes(x=popu_H0, y=popu_H0_norm))
plot_H0 + 
  geom_line() +
  theme(
    text = element_text(size=20), 
    axis.title.x = element_text(vjust=0.1),
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = rel(1.8)),
    legend.position = "none",
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    axis.line.y = element_blank()
  ) +
  xlab("New label") +
  annotate("text", x = 20, y = 0.05, label = "Some annotation", size = 10) 

grid.arrange(plot_H0, plot_H0, plot_H0, ncol = 1, nrow = 3)
```

`ggplot` produces the expected output, but `grid.arrange` produces [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwIzN.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to replace the plot object.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
popu_H0 <- seq(10, 30, length=100)
popu_H0_norm <- dnorm(popu_H0, mean = 20, sd = 4)

popu_H0_df <- as.data.frame(cbind(popu_H0, popu_H0_norm))
plot_H0 <- ggplot(popu_H0_df, aes(x=popu_H0, y=popu_H0_norm))
plot_H0 <- plot_H0 +   # Here you need `<-` to update the plot 
  geom_line() +
  theme(
    text = element_text(size=20), 
    axis.title.x = element_text(vjust=0.1),
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = rel(1.8)),
    legend.position = "none",
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    axis.line.y = element_blank()
  ) +
  xlab("New label") +
  annotate("text", x = 20, y = 0.05, label = "Some annotation", size = 10) 

grid.arrange(plot_H0, plot_H0, plot_H0, ncol = 1, nrow = 3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, am I missing something? The code you've posted looks identical to mine except you have (correctly) added the library calls at the top. Perhaps the clue is in "you forgot to replace the plot object" but I don't know what this means! If you are referring to the fact that I've used the same plot 3 times, I can confirm that the behaviour is exactly the same with three different plot objects. I only posted it this way to make the example simple and reproducible.

Comment: I have `plot_H0 <- ` in the 7th line.  I add comment there.